Contradicting Answers to a Parabola Problem
and sorry for my bad english. I encountered this problem in a textbook in my native language and it seems that 2 different approaches yield two different answers, so I will give both these solutions and ask where the problem is.

The problem:
$$f(x) = {2\over3} (x-3)(x+1)$$
What is the product of the roots of the following equation in Real numbers?
$$f(x+2) = x-1$$

The first solution:
Convert the parabola $f(x)$ to $f(x+2)$, yielding:
$f(x+2) = 2/3(x-1)(x+3)$, and when solved for when it equals $x-1$, it yields two real roots with a product of $-3/2$.
The second solution:
Convert the (second) $f(x+2)$ equation to $f(x)$, yielding:
$f(x) = x-3$, and when the parabola is solved like so:
$f(x) = 2/3(x-3)(x+1) = x-3$. The product of the roots of this equation turns out to be $3/2$.
Thank you in advance.

Have you translated the problem correctly? The only thing your second sentence requests is “the product of the roots” of the equation “$f(x+2)=x-1$”. Since it involves a polynomial of degree 1, it cannot have more than a single root. Thus the product of its roots is undefined.

@PaulTanenbaum  $f(x+2)=(x-1)$ means $\frac 23(x+2-3)(x+2+1)=x-1$ which is quadratic.

For your second solution, note that we are asking for values of $x$ which make $f(x+2)=x-1$ true.  You can certainly change variables, letting $y=x+2$, say,  which would give us $f(y)=y-3$ BUT solutions to that are not solutions to the original problem.  In particular, $y=3$ solves the translated equation, but $x=3$ does not solve the original.  You need to reverse the translation to get solutions to the original.

@lulu, I know how to do the plug and chug, but I was not fully confident that even the gist of the translation was correct.

@PaulTanenbaum  I'm just pointing out that, as the equation is quadratic, it has two roots.  In principle these could coincide, but the equation is $\frac 23(x-1)(x+3)=(x-1)$ so one root is $x=1$ and the other isn't.

@lulu, and I’m just pointing out that in isolation, the sentence asks about the roots of “$f(x+2)=x-1$,” and that equation is the same as “$f(u)=u-3$.” That latter equation has but one root, which is $u=3$, which would mean $x=-1$.

@PaulTanenbaum  I don't understand.  The equation $f(u)=u-3$ obviously has two roots.  Writing out $f(u)$ we get $f(u)=\frac 23(u-3)(u+1)$ setting that to $u-3$ we see that $u=3$ is indeed a root.  Dividing by $u-3$ gives $\frac 23(u+1)=1$ or $(u+1)=\frac 32$ so $u=\frac 12$ is a second root.  The roots of the translated equation are therefore $3$ and $\frac 12$.

@lulu, $y = f(u) = u - 3$ is the equation of the line in the $uy$-plane with slope 1 and $y$-intercept $y=3$. And $u=1/2$ is not a root of this linear equation. That’s my point. As I wrote above, “in isolation [emphasis added], the sentence asks about the roots of [an equation that] is the same as $f(u)=u-3$.”

@lulu f was not redefined, thus the second equation is not isolated from the first one, and I have checked the translation.

@user23107035  Yes, i understand.  I don't think there is any confusion at all in the problem statement.  $f(x+1)=x-1$ asks for the two intersections between a parabola and a line.  Your first solution is correct, the second one is incorrect because you neglected to unwind the change of variables.

@Intelligenti pauca But why does the conversion translate the roots of the second equation I cannot understand this part, I have tried to visualize it with graphs but cannot come to a full grasp of what is going on here. Can you provide a more detailed explanation of the topic please? Thank you so much for all the answers by the way.

The solutions are the $x$ coordinates of the intersection points between line and parabola. If line and parabola get translated along $x$ by $2$ units, the intersection points are also translated by the same amount.

@Intelligentipauca But isn't the translation of f(x+2) = x-1 to f(x) = x-3 like asking what are the points of intersection between f(x) and x-3 which are also the points where f(x+2) and x-1 intersect, isn't this the reasonnig behind conversion, at least that was what I thought when doing the conversion.

You must translate the points back, to get the same result. As lulu pointed out, try to use another letter (e.g. $x'$) for the translated curves: you'll get $x'_1=1/2$, whence $x_1=1/2-2=-3/2$.

@Intelligentipauca Thank you so much for you answer I appreciate it.

@lulu Thank you so much for you answer I appreciate it.

As there appears to be some confusion in the comments:
The graph of $f(x)$ is a parabola.  We can ask for the intersection of that parabola with a line...a priori that could be $0$ points, $1$ point (with multiplicity $2$) or $2$ points.  In this case it is $2$ points.
Your first solution is exactly right.  $$f(x+2)=(x-1)\implies \frac 23(x-1)(x+3)=x-1\implies x\in \{1, -\frac 32\}$$ so the desired answer is $1\times\left( -\frac 32\right)=-\frac 32$
The second solution is incorrect, or rather incomplete.  What you tried to do was to change variables.  Letting $y=x+2$ the desired equation reads $$f(y)=y-3$$
That implies that $$\frac 23(y-3)(y+1)=y-3\implies y\in \{3, \frac 12\}$$
But, of course, $y$ is not $x$ and we were asked for $x$, not $y$.  Noting that $x=y-2$ We see that $y=3\implies x=1$ and $y=\frac 12\implies x=-\frac 32$ so we have recovered the (correct) first solution.
I think you confused yourself by calling the "new" variable $x$, just like the old one.  to convince yourself that this is unjustified, try setting $x=3$ in the desired equation.  It would give "$f(5)=2$" but that is easily seen to be false.

Parabola $y=f(x+2)$ is obtained from parabola $y=f(x)$ by translating it by $-2$ in the direction of $x$-axis. Hence the solutions of your second equation $f(x)=x-3$ are translated by $+2$ with respect to the solutions of the first one:
solutions of the first equation: $x_1=-{3\over2}$, $x_2=1$;
solutions of the second equation: $x_1={1\over2}$, $x_2=3$.
It's just by chance that their products are opposite.
EDIT.
Here's a diagram with the first parabola-line pair (red) and the second one (blue), to show how the intersection points are translated.

